# How to prove that if $f^2=f$ then $V= \ker f + \operatorname{Im} f$.

Tags: linear-algebra

I need help to solve this algebra problem.

Having $f$, an endomorphism, and knowing that $f(f(v))$ is equal to $f(v)$, I need to prove that $V=  \operatorname{Ker}f +  \operatorname{Im}f$,  being complementary. 
I also need to show that if we reduce $f$ to $ \operatorname{Im}f$, What we have is the identity application.

I have already proved that if $\dim V=n$ and $\dim  \operatorname{Ker}f=s$ , $\dim  \operatorname{Im}f=n-s$, but I don´t know how to justify that $0_V$ is the only vector in the intersection.

It would be amazing if you helped me.

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: assume there is a vector other than $0v$ in the intersection and see what happens.

Comment: Related: [Suppose $T$ is an operation on a vector space $V$ and $T^2=T.$ Prove that $V=N(T)\oplus R(T).$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/704967/721644)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $v \in V$ then $v=f(v) +(v-f(v))$. Since the first term belongs to image of $f$ and $f(v-f(v))=f(v)-f(f(v))=f(v)-f(v)=0$ we see that the second term belongs to kernel of $f$. Hence $V =\ker (f) +Im (f)$. If $v \in ker (f) \cap Im(f)$ then $v=f(w)$ for some $w$. Hence $f(v)=f(f(w))=f(w)=v$ but $f(v)=0$. Hence $v=0$. It follows that $ker (f) \cap Im(f)=\{0\}$. Finally, if $v \in Im(f)$ then  $v=f(w)$ for some $w$. Hence $f(v)=f(f(w))=f(w)=v$ so $f$ is the identity map on $Im (f)$.

Comment: Why is $v= f(v) + (v-(f(v))$? I don´t understand it

Comment: $f(v)+(v-f(v))=f(v)+v-f(v)=v.$

Answer (score 2):

For all $x \in V$ we have $x=f(x)+(x-f(x))$. Since $f^2=f$, we have $x-f(x) \in ker(f)$, hence $x=f(x)+(x-f(x) \in Im(f)+ker(f).$

Comment: The question also asks to show they are complementary spaces. That would mean showing that $Im(f)$ is closed.