# About idempotent lineal transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a vector space and $T: V \to V$ a linear transformation, $T$ is idempotent $(T\circ T=T).$ I must  prove that $\operatorname{Im}(T)+\operatorname{Nu}(T)=V,$ where $\operatorname{Im}$ is the image of $T$ and $\operatorname{Nu}$ the null space.

I started by trying to show that  $\operatorname{Im}(T)+\operatorname{Nu}(T)$ is contained in $V$ and after that show that $V$ is contained in $\operatorname{Im}(T)+\operatorname{Nu}(T)$.

The first step is pretty easy and don’t need a lot of work cause if a vector, let it be $w$, exist in $\operatorname{Im}(T)+\operatorname{Nu}(T)$ then if exist in $\operatorname{Im}(T)$ by definition of $T$ that vector exist in $V$ and if exist in $\operatorname{Ker}(T)$ then, by definition of null space, exist in $V$.

But now the second step is the harder for me, I have no idea even where to start. I noticed that I can define $w= T(a) + b$ an then say that there exist some $x$ in $V$ that is defined as $x= T(a)$ and redefine $w$ as $w= T(x) + b'= T(T(a)) + b' = T(a)+b'$ but I can’t see nothing else to do, so any kind of help is very appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You really don't have to show $\operatorname{Im}(T)+\operatorname{Nu}(T)$ is a subspace. If you know both $\operatorname{Im}(T)$ and $\operatorname{Nu}(T)$ are subspace of $V.$ Their sum is a vector space by definition.

Comment: Also duplicate of [Suppose $T$ is an operation on a vector space $V$ and $T^2=T.$ Prove that $V=N(T)\oplus R(T).$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/704967/721644).